# Does the existence of Higgs imply the existence of Magnetic Monopoles?

Tags: standard-model, symmetry-breaking, topology, magnetic-monopoles, solitons

I am aware that in theories with spontaneous symmetry breaking, [Magnetic Monopoles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole) can exist as [topological solitons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_defect). Can the same be done with the Standard Model gauge group. I am familiar with the contents of 't Hooft's paper [Magnetic Monopoles in Unified Gauge theories](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/gthpub/magnetic_monopoles.pdf). But the analysis in that paper is done for the $\operatorname{SO}(3)$ gauge group.

Is there a similar analysis for the standard model gauge group? Does the discovery of Higgs particle imply the existence of magnetic monopoles as topological solitons, and magnetic charge being treated as a topological charge?

Answer (score 7):

No, I believe the Standard Model does not predict monopoles as a result of symmetry breaking. This is because the symmetry breaking $\mathrm{SU(2)} \times \mathrm{U(1)} \rightarrow \mathrm{U(1)}$ does not allow for topological solitons to exist.

Edit: $\pi_2(\mathrm{SU(2)} \times \mathrm{U(1)}/\mathrm{U(1))}=\pi_2(S^3)=0$

Source: [To be or not to be? Magnetic monopoles in non-abelian gauge theories by F. Alexander Bais](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0407197)

Comment: Interesting, Can you please elaborate the on the calculation of the Homotopy group.In specific Why is SU(2)*U(1)/U(1) The same as S3.

Comment: @Prathyush Unfortunately, I'm not sure ho to calculate this (I've read it in some sources, for instance http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0407197). However, I would be very interested to know how to calculate this, so maybe anybody else could explain this or provide some references?

Comment: I offered a bounty hopefully some one will notice.