# Have magnetic monopoles been predicted to have been produced in other cases than those of symmetry breaking in GUTs?

Tags: black-holes, symmetry-breaking, magnetic-monopoles, grand-unification

Also, what other configurations are magnetic monopoles theorized to exist in? (such as black holes, monopole walls etc.)

Comment: You might be interested in [this question, which is related to the prediction by Cho and Maison of a magnetic monopole in the Standard Model](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/323510/168783) (although it behaves differently than the GUT ones)

Comment: See also the links therein